# python csv writing SET values

Tags: csv, set, python-3.6

Python 3.6

I am trying to write set values to CSV , I am getting the following output for the given code.

```
import csv

class test_write:

    @classmethod
    def test_write1(cls):
        fieldnames1 = ['first_name', 'last_name']
        cls.write_a_test1(fieldnames=fieldnames1)

    @classmethod
    def write_a_test1(cls, fieldnames):
        with open('/Users/Desktop/delete1.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writeheader()
            abc = cls.var1()
            writer.writerow(abc)
        print("Done writing")

    @staticmethod
    def var1():
        d = ('my', 'name', 'is', 'hahaha')
        c = set()
        abc = {'first_name': c, 'last_name': d}
        return abc


test_write.test_write1()
```

When I open CSV file:
Output:

```
first_name  last_name
set()   ('my', 'name', 'is', 'hahaha')
```

I don't want it to print set() in the file if it is empty. Instead I need blank. Variable 'C' might have or might not have values it depends. How do I proceed with that.

Answer (score 0):

`Dictwriter` expects the keys and values to be strings, so `str` is being called on the objects.  What you should use is something like:

```
d = ('my', 'name', 'is', 'hahaha')
c = set()
abc = {'first_name': ' '.join(c), 'last_name': ' '.join(d)}
return abc
```

The the result of the file will be:

```
first_name,last_name
,my name is hahaha
```